# Modules for Beginners

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know that this may not be the appropriate destination to ask such a dummy question, but unfortunately I know no different destination to ask for help.

Can anybody recommend me a book in modules for beginners, a book that covers various types of modules such that free modules, injective and projective modules, and so on?. I currently read about modules from **Graduate text in mathematics for** ***Thomas W. Hungerford***. But the book is somehow difficult for a beginner like me.

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I find the modules chapter in Dummit and Foote to be pretty accessible.

Comment: Aluffi's _Algebra: Chapter 0_ is also a very nice introduction.

Comment: I like *Module Theory: An Approach to Linear Algebra* by T. S. Blyth.

Comment: Modules: A primer of Structure Theorems by Thomas J Head, covers exactly what you want.